Chrome Version 128.0.6613.85 Web driver issue
I have chrome browser of Version 128.0.6613.85 and i want to download the correct webdriver for it.
I checked the official webdriver website but i can't find the correct version for it. i want the webdriver for this version.

-Win 64 link- :
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/128.0.6613.84/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
-Win 32 link- :
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/128.0.6613.84/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip

Issue is still persisting, Message: Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9 Chrome latest version is 128.0.6613.85 and driver latest and stable version is this 128.0.6613.84

You can download the version you need from this website:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

This may also be useful https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Here it is:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json
You can find an older version before 114.0.5735.90 on this page:
https://registry.npmmirror.com/binary.html?path=chromedriver/
